# Why does my Google Login session expire on some pages but not others?

Tags: php, session, authentication, google-api, google-oauth

So I am learning how to use Google's Oauth system to allow users to login in with their Google account. I have been using this recourse [here](http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-google-api-using-php/): to implement it on my website.

So on my test page when I try to login and then change pages, the user is still successfully logged in.

However, when I then take the PHP code from the test page, place it in my global header - when the user tries to access the same link. Once the user logs in, as soon as they go to another page, they are automatically logged out.

The code on the test2 page is exactly the same as their index page example. On my header I have added it into my navbar so the login button is inside the modal when the user presses Sign In on the navbar.

The link used in test2 is the same used in my header:

```html
  <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google" <?php echo "href='".filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)."'" ?>>
    <span class="fa fa-google"></span> Sign in with Google
  </a>
```

I have used this if statement to check if the user is logged in. If they are logged in it will show the dropdown with the account options, else they are shown the login button which opens the modal. Maybe this is the problem, rather than their session expiring, could it be really I am checking the wrong function?

```html
<?php if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) { ?>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="accountmenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
<?php echo $gpUserProfile['given_name'] ?>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="accountdropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="/user/bookmarks">Bookmarks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal" id="login">Sign In</a>
<?php } ?>
```

The full header code can be seen here if would help: https://hastebin.com/izihuhavep.scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to fix it, for some reason when the PHP code to create a session is in the head it does not work. Not sure why, but when I moved it above the head it worked perfectly :)